# How to remove downlight with mouse trap clips

Tags: light-fixture, light, recessed-lighting

See attached pic. I have downlights like this in my apartment. I don't know how to get at the mouse trap clips. I can pull down on the downlight at the seal with the roof but then I need to flick the clips on the left and right up. How can I do this? With a thin knife maybe?[image: mouse trap downlight]

Comment: Be careful if you're renting.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you just need to pull harder - mouse trap implies spring loaded, and you need to pull until they fold back up into the position they would have been in to be installed.

Comment: Those are spring loaded once you overcome the spring force they release. Many fixtures are like this.

Comment: Might have to wiggle back and forth a bit if hole was cut too small.+1